# Navigator for ArcGIS integration with a laptop via bluetooth

Tags: gps, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-navigator

Does anyone know how to integrate [Navigator for ArcGIS](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/navigator/) with a laptop via bluetooth to display location information/point locations from a web app residing on a laptop?

Or can I just call the Navigator service via the bluetooth connection?